# Why in my Eclipse Oxigen not found Struts1?

Tags: eclipse

When I make a project web dynamic, I am going to add struts1 in a File, new, other, and select a wizard in folder Amateras.

I don't see support for adding Struts1.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen in Windows 10.

Comment: (Please try using a spelling checker.) Is `Amateras` a name chosen by you? Is there anything that makes `folder Amateras` special: what happens if you try to `add struts1` "in a different folder"?

Comment: Where are you seeing something to make you expect that support?